# How to read tags out of m4a files in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, tags, windows-media-player, m4a

I've got [some heavily modified code that ultimately came from the Windows Media SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/SqlLinq.aspx) that works great for reading tags out of MP3 and [WMV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video) files. Somewhere along the line, Windows Media Player added support for [.m4a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#.MP4_versus_.M4A_file_extensions) files (was it in Windows 7?) but the Windows Media API doesn't seem to reflect that addition (or at least `IWMMetadataEditor2::OpenEx` pukes on an .m4a file).

What would be some good C# code or links on how to dig meta data tags out of m4a files? (Google has come up dry on the C# front.)

**UPDATE**
AtomicParsley did indeed end up being the best approach. Since that code is a command line tool however I ended up having to create a managed wrapper around some of its functionality in order to use in-process. [It is posted on google code](http://code.google.com/p/m4sharp/) if anyone else needs such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some opensource software that does what you are looking for, although it is in C++ (maybe it contains some useful information)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/atomicparsley/

Here is a project using winforms to achieve what you are wanting.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/m4afiletags.aspx

I tried the same thing as above to see if there was something he was missing in getting it to work in a console application, but I was unable to get it working without using the ActiveX control used on the Winforms project.

Comment: The atomic parsely code looks like it's got what I need (though it'll need some work to make .net callable). Thanks again.